# Simplify $P=1-\left( 364 \times 363 \cdots \cdots \frac{364-N+1}{364^N} \right)$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Show that after simplification of $P=1-\left( 364 \times 363 \cdots \cdots \frac{364-N+1}{364^N} \right)$, we get the result $$P=1-e^{-\frac{N(N-1)}{2 *364}}. $$

**Answer:**

We have,

$P=1-\left( 364 \times 363 \cdots \ \cdots \frac{364-N+1}{364^N} \right) \\ \Rightarrow P=1-\frac{364 \times 363 \cdots \ \cdots (364-N+1)}{364 \times 364 \times 364 \cdots \ \cdots 364 \ (N \ times)}$

But then how to proceed ?

help me

Comment: This is not a simplification but an approximation.

Comment: @kimchilover, How do I do this approximation ?

Comment: Use logarithms and the approximation $\log(1-x) = -x -x^2/3\cdots$ as explained in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem